# Injecting a service / constant with a namespaced name like "com.application.configs"

Tags: angularjs

I have a constant service defined like:

```
myModule.constant("com.application.configs",{language: "EN"});
```

And now I want to inject this into my controller but I don't know how to achieve this using a constant name with dots like that.

```
myModule.controller("dialogController",function ($scope, com.application.configs) {...})
```

Obviously this doesn't work but I don't know how to do this injection or if this is possible without doing the manual $inject.

How can I correctly use a service / constant like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use dot in variable names. Try

```
myModule.controller("dialogController",['$scope', 'com.application.configs', function ($scope, applicationConfigs) {...})
```

'com.application.configs' should be injected as applicationConfigs